# I want to create a spinner like Dinner Spinner

Tags: iphone

I want to create a spinner like Dinner Spinner.

I am approximately there by using UIPicker.
but thing which I cant achieve is after rotating on button press, **stopping the spinner animation softly**.

Comment: How are you doing the animation now?

Comment: A really good question, +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have deceleration effect in UIPickerView. Looking at the dinner spinner app, i think they have used scrollview there.

UPDATE:

As far as scroll view is concerned, you need to play with

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

for table view.

But this approach works if you have enough items in the scroll view to show for enough spinning time. I mean, what if you reach the end item and you still want to spin?

Here, you need to do all things manually and it isn't hard. I have made slot machine application where i made the custom spinner.

And it works something like this…

You could have items A, B, C, D and E from which B, C and D are visible. You keep shifting each of them left (or right) firing NSTimer. And when the leftmost item goes out of bounds, put it to the extreme right. This will give an illusion that the items are circular.

And after some time has elapsed you can get the decelerating effect by reducing the shifting (acceleration) by arithmetic progression or geometric progression.

Comment: It's mostly a rotated `UITableView` object. It has been a trend.

Comment: I have also try with ScrollView but same result, scrollview stops instantly. Do you have any idea to scroll it fast and stop smoothly.

Comment: I respect your words, but this is possible for slot machine but here user can interact with the spinner any time. I have tried it what you said and some what I achieved but I thing thats not the right way. What ever I used TableView or Picker or Scroller all they have to give a particular point to go and animate and when ever they reached there they all create a Garek / Stopped instantly by using NSTimer I give a near point to stop softly but.... yes it create illusion of soft ending but by viewing it gently it gives a GAREK before starting a soft ending animation.